# how to get the list of child nodes for each treeview parent

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

i followed a tutorial and here is the link http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/, its working fine but i need to loop each parent and retrieve its child node

so far this is my code

```
        foreach (Family item in trvFamilies.Items)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
```

how do i retrieve the list of child node for each parent? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this :

```
        foreach (Family item in trvFamilies.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            var members = item.Members;
        }
```